# BeautifulSoup - getting value from the resultant tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The below code is my python code with beautiful soup for getting a specified value from a given URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

book = urllib.urlopen(url)
bookpage = book.read()
book.close()            
booksoup=BeautifulSoup(bookpage)
bookTags=booksoup.findAll('div',{"class":"hotel_large_photp_score featured_review_score"})
print bookTags
```

and when I print the `bookTags` this is what I got (below)

```
<div class="hotel_large_photp_score featured_review_score">
<a class="big_review_score_detailed js-big_review_score_detailed ind_rev_total hp_review_score" data-component="track" data-hash="cPWbOTCcdSdCBYSbfYCWXT" data-stage="1" data-tab-link="" data-track="click" href="#blockdisplay4" onclick="return false;" rel="reviews" style="">
<span data-component="track" data-hash="cPWbOTCcdSdCBYSbfYCWXT" data-stage="5" data-track="click">
<span class=" ">
Very good
</span>
<span class="rating">
<span class="average">8.2</span><span class="out_of">/<span class="best">10</span></span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
<span class="trackit score_from_number_of_reviews">
Score from <strong class="count">229</strong> reviews
</span>
```

What I need is the value `8.2` from the tag `<span class="average">8.2</span>`. Please help me to get that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
average = bookTags.find("span", {"class": "average"})
print average.text
```

Comment: No the Html document has many tags with <class="avaerage">. That is why I retrieved its Parent tag.

Comment: yeah but you are only searching the parent tag

Comment: `for bookTag in bookTags:        
        Rate= bookTag.find('span',{"class":"average"})
        print Rate.text`  this worked for me. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

```
bookTags=booksoup.findAll('div',{"class":"hotel_large_photp_score featured_review_score"})
for bookTag in bookTags:        
        Rate= bookTag.find('span',{"class":"average"})
        print Rate.text
```

any way this worked for me. Thank You for your effort